# I want to create my own plugin for Azkaban

Tags: azkaban

I'm trying to do what I wrote at this mail's subject.

But the number of the information on the internet seems very few.

Does anyone know about that or helpful webpages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree. I am trying to find similar information. I have just found this until now. Maybe indirectly helpful to you.

http://submitteddenied.github.io/azkaban2/documents/2.1/createnewjobtypes.html

It talks about creating new job types. Not sure what kind of plugin you are creating but I was creating a new job type plugin and I came across this.

I also found their google group pretty helpful. You may want to post there too https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/azkaban-dev

I know this is not the exact answer you were looking for but hopefully it helps.

Comment: This maybe helpful to https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban-plugins/wiki/How-To-Install 
This shows how the plugin is installed in the azkaban which will be helpful to know how the main framework is including the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for getting me some links!
I'll check it out from now.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.